# adding multiple class objects to a single list and returning the values from the objects

Tags: c#, list, object

I am a beginner and have searched for a simple example to my problem without success.  I have two classes, and would like to add class objects to a single list and then print the values from the classes to the console. I apologize if this has been answered before.

```
class onetwo
{

}    
class classOne:onetwo
{
    int item1 = 10;
    int item2 = 11;            
}
class classTwo:onetwo
{
    string item3 = "red";
    string item4 = "blue";
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        classOne numbers = new classOne();
        classTwo colors = new classTwo();
        List<onetwo> listC1 = new List<onetwo>();
        listC1.Add(numbers);
        listC1.Add(colors);

        foreach (onetwo e in listC1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

     }
  }
}

//program output is
//objects_added_to_list.classOne
//objects_added_to_list.classTwo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an overload of the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method for each class:

```
class classOne:onetwo
{
    int item1 = 10;
    int item2 = 11; 

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("item1: {0}, item2: {1}", item1, item2);
    }       
}

class classTwo:onetwo
{
    string item3 = "red";
    string item4 = "blue";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("item3: {0}, item4: {1}", item3, item4);
    }       
}
```

---

Another alternative is to provide a custom method in your base class to generate a formatted string via reflection:

```
class onetwo
{
    public virtual string ToPrintableString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", 
            this.GetType()
                .GetFields()
                .Select(p => p.Name + ": " + p.GetValue(this));
    }
} 

...

foreach (onetwo e in listC1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToPrintableString());
}
```

Note this method uses reflection, so it's not very fast (which is why I didn't implement it in an override of `ToString`), and I wouldn't recommend it *in general*, but it would work for your case.

Comment: Wow.. Identical to my answer.  I guess I'll delete it.  It's erie at how similar they are.

Comment: The first parameter to your String.Format in classTwo is set to `item4` when it should be `item3`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I am going to read about public override string.  I have not seen this before.